# JavaScript find matching object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hi I have an array of objects

```
[
       {
         outletId: 619734
         tleaderId: "3f8be9bf-5920-4d3d-b915-50ca76cb21oo"
       },
       {
         outletId: 619755
         tleaderId: "3f8be9bf-5920-4d3d-b915-50ca76cb24ty"   
       },
       {
         outletId: 619700
         tleaderId: "3f8be9bf-5920-4d3d-b915-50ca76cb2qwe"  
       }
       // and so on...
]
```

Then I'm creating another object

```
[
       {
         outletId: 619734
         tleaderId: "3f8be9bf-5920-4d3d-b915-50ca76cb21oo"
       }
]
```

And I want to find if the new created object matches any of the object in the array. I tried this with no luck

```
$.each(objCollection, function () {
      if (this === newObject) {
         alert("Already exist!!!");
      }
});
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: show me where you instanciate newObject

Comment: The `===` operator is only going to work if they're literally the same object. Not just have the same properties, but refer to the same memory address. You'll need a function that compares two objects that you can call.

Comment: yes ok you said it "Then I'm creating another object" it's a new object so it will never be the same. Make a function to compare the two objects like @AnthonyGrist said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want something like this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b27qj/7/) ?

```
var array = [{
    outletId: 619734,
    tleaderId: "3f8be9bf-5920-4d3d-b915-50ca76cb21oo"
}, {
    outletId: 619755,
    tleaderId: "3f8be9bf-5920-4d3d-b915-50ca76cb24ty"
}, {
    outletId: 619700,
    tleaderId: "3f8be9bf-5920-4d3d-b915-50ca76cb2qwe"
}
// and so on...
]

var newArray = [{
    outletId: 619734,
    tleaderId: "3f8be9bf-5920-4d3d-b915-50ca76cb21oo"
}];

function matchCase(array1,array2){

    var matchFound = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

        item = array1[i];

        if (item.outletId === array2[0].outletId && item.tleaderId === array2[0].tleaderId) {

            matchFound = true;
            break;

        }
    }

    return matchFound;

}

console.log(matchCase(array,newArray));
```

Comment: IMHO, that callback passing is _horrible_, and completely unnecessary, and doesn't provide sensible logic for the case when the entry _isn't_ found.  The code isn't async, so just have `matchCase` return a boolean.

Comment: ... Why did you add a callback like that? o.O

Comment: @Cerbrus, Just did it the hard way, didn't think of the case that I can simply return the found item if any, and if nothing is found return "".

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var exists = array.some(function(obj){
    return obj.outletId == search.outletId && obj.tleaderId == search.tleaderId;
});

if(exists){
    alert("Already exist!!!");
}
```

This assumes the object you're looking for is stored in a `search` variable:

```
var search = {
    outletId: 619734
    tleaderId: "3f8be9bf-5920-4d3d-b915-50ca76cb21oo"
}
```

Comment: This is not gonna work based on OP example cuz search object is inside an array so you need to write `search[0].outletId` and `search[0].tleaderId`

Comment: Actually you want `array.some`, not `array.filter`.  Not only does it automatically give you a boolean result, it short circuits the `for` loop as soon as a match is found.

Comment: @Mauro74 IMHO this should have been the accepted answer

Comment: @Alnitak I need it to work in IE8 so the accepted answer I've picked is the one that works best for my project.

Comment: @Mauro74: I'd suggest using the **[polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Compatibility)** provided in the MDN's documentation for IE8 compatibility.

Comment: @Mauro74 using polyfills as Cerberus suggests really is the way to go - learn how to write using modern JS features _now_, and patch the browsers that don't support them with polyfills.  Your code will improve.

Answer (score -1):

linking: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/taN4Z/
//checking new array values within old one

```
    $.each(obj2, function (key1,val1) {
      $.each(obj1, function (key2,val2) {
        if(val1.outletId==val2.outletId){
           alert("Already exist!!!"+val1.outletId);
        }
     });     
   });
```

Here obj2 ( new array ) values are checked with the old array ( obj1 ) values .